# Installing Patch Management from ITSM

Tags: windows-installer

I am trying to install patch manager from ITSM - I have used the following cmd line:

/qn AGENTUSERNAME=xxxxxxx PASSWORD=xxxx CUSTOMER=xxxx IPADDRESS=patch.comodo.com

I have also tried it with commas "/qn AGENTUSERNAME=xxxxxxx PASSWORD=xxxx CUSTOMER=xxxx IPADDRESS=patch.comodo.com"

In the MSI Installation State, I have the following message:

"https://patch.comodo.com/agents/patch_agent.msi

Installation failed (1639 - Invalid command line argument.)

I did get it working before and have tried on several different computers - same result.

Installation manually works fine.

Comment: What do the docs in the *Command-line options* Read more link say? [Is this the right thing?](https://help.comodo.com/topic-399-1-786-10139-.html#install_th_pr_packages) I suspect the `/qn` could be the problem, but I have no experience with ITSM and can't find the correct docs. (I also find it odd to pass a hostname to a property called IPADDRESS, but maybe it's just a misleading name.)

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on how you want to utilize Comodo ONE. Here are links of what these two can do for you and your clients.

ITSM --> https://help.comodo.com/topic-399-1-786-10078-Introduction-to-Comodo-IT-and-Security-Manager.html

PM --> https://help.comodo.com/topic-289-1-718-8500-Introduction-to-the-Patch-Management-Module.html

Based on the introductions of each one, you can definitely find out which of the two will fit your needs for the task at hand. Both are made available to our MSPs so that they can go as 'lite' (PM) as they want with C1 or go 'fully-featured' (ITSM) if they need to do more than patching on their client's devices.